# Backup fails unless compression is enabled

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, backup

I'm trying to back up a DB to a network share. The backup fails every time with the same error:

```
BackupIoRequest::ReportIoError: write failure on backup device '\\share_name\Backups\filename.bak'. Operating system error 64(The specified network name is no longer available.).
```

This happens on *just one* database out of 88 databases on the SQL server. All of the others are being backed up daily - to the same location - with no problems.

**What I have tried:**

- Checked share/folder permissions (all ok)
- Manual backup to a network share on a completely different storage system (same error)
- Adding sesstimeout to the registry [as suggested here](https://dirkhondong.wordpress.com/2012/01/27/the-specified-network-name-is-no-longer-available-sql-backup-problem-solved/) (same error)
- DBCC checkdb on the offending DB (no issues)

Backing up to local disk isn't an option because there's not enough storage available locally.

Now, the strange thing is, when I enable compression the backup magically works! Whereas if I don't, I see the backup file appear on the share and after about 2 minutes the file disappears and the backup fails with the error above.

I'm at a loss and looking for any ideas about what might be causing this.

Comment: This seems problem with network share how is this configured is it on any 32 bit machine ?. Compressing backup requires less I/O as compared to uncompressed so with compression it is working.

Comment: I agree that sounds like a network issue. Is this database bigger than the other ones? Maybe by compressing it you get it under a certain size after which the connection drops.

Comment: I thought the same thing at first, but this DB is about 1/2 the size of the largest one on the server.  It is a 64 bit machine.

Comment: Do you use Named Pipes Protocol? Did you try back up using specific IP address instead of share name? Have you tried setting sesstimeout even higher?

Comment: Named Pipes is disabled.  I'll try your suggestions of using the IP and increasing sesstimeout.

Comment: Sounds like you have AntiVirus running on the server where the share is located, and it is detecting what it thinks is a virus when doing the backup without compression.  When the backup is compressed the AntiVirus does not recognize the data as containing a virus.